# Merge flat associative array with an indexed array of associative rows to form flat associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I want to combine two arrays. How can I do this?

**First Array:**

```
    Array
    (
        [E1] => #43
        [B3] => Onur KAYA
        [B4] => 0555555555
        [B5] => demo@gmail.com
        [E3] => 1
        [E4] => 2017-12-24 14:31:11
        [E5] => 2018-05-26 15:17:48
        [B7] => 2018-05-16 15:33:06
        [B8] => Taslak
        [B9] => 2018-10-08 - 2019-03-11
        [B10] => 4,7363 TL 
        [B11] => 71.708 TL ($15,140 )
        [E7] => Amerika / Kaliforniya
        [E8] => Okul / Kampüs
        [E9] => Genel Akademik Sömestir - 5 ay / Sabit Tarihli
        [E10] => indirim kuponu - 33.376 TL ($7,570 )
        [E11] => 35.854 TL ($7,570 )
        [C12] => 2.368 TL ($500 )
        [F12] => 35.854 TL ($7,570 )
    )
```

**Second Array**

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [A15] => Kurs Ücreti (Genel Akademik Sömestir - 5 ay)
            [D15] => 22 Hafta
            [E15] => $8,200 
            [F15] => $8,200 
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [A16] => Konaklama Ücreti (Aile Yanı İki Kişilik - 14 öğün/hafta (AKADEMİK SÖMESTİR 5 AY - 22 HAFTAYA KADAR))
            [D16] => 22 Hafta
            [E16] => $4,695 
            [F16] => $4,695 
        )

        [2] => Array
        (
            [A17] => Transfer (Oakland Havaalanı'nden Transfer Hizmeti)
            [D17] => Tek yön
            [E17] => $145 
            [F17] => $145 
        )

        [3] => Array
        (
            [A18] => Kayıt Ücreti
            [D18] => 1
            [E18] => $185 
            [F18] => $185 
        )

        [4] => Array
        (
            [A19] => Üniversite Yerleştirme Servisi - Temel
            [D19] => 1
            [E19] => $175 
            [F19] => $175 
        )

        [5] => Array
        (
            [A20] => Seyahat ve Sağlık Sigortası
            [D20] => 22 Hafta
            [E20] => $45 
            [F20] => $990 
        )

        [6] => Array
        (
            [A21] => Birebir Ders
            [D21] => 10
            [E21] => $75 
            [F21] => $750 
        )

    )
```

**The result I want**

```
    Array
    (
        [E1] => #43
        [B3] => Onur KAYA
        [B4] => 0555555555
        [B5] => demo@gmail.com
        [E3] => 1
        [E4] => 2017-12-24 14:31:11
        [E5] => 2018-05-26 15:17:48
        [B7] => 2018-05-16 15:33:06
        [B8] => Taslak
        [B9] => 2018-10-08 - 2019-03-11
        [B10] => 4,7363 TL
        [B11] => 71.708 TL ($15,140 )
        [E7] => Amerika / Kaliforniya
        [E8] => Okul / Kampüs
        [E9] => Genel Akademik Sömestir - 5 ay / Sabit Tarihli
        [E10] => indirim kuponu - 33.376 TL ($7,570 )
        [E11] => 35.854 TL ($7,570 )
        [C12] => 2.368 TL ($500 )
        [F12] => 35.854 TL ($7,570 )
        [A15] => Kurs Ücreti (Genel Akademik Sömestir - 5 ay)
        [D15] => 22 Hafta
        [E15] => $8,200
        [F15] => $8,200
        [A16] => Konaklama Ücreti (Aile Yanı İki Kişilik - 14 öğün/hafta (AKADEMİK SÖMESTİR 5 AY - 22 HAFTAYA KADAR))
        [D16] => 22 Hafta
        [E16] => $4,695
        [F16] => $4,695
        [A17] => Transfer (Oakland Havaalanı'nden Transfer Hizmeti)
        [D17] => Tek yön
        [E17] => $145
        [F17] => $145
        [A18] => Kayıt Ücreti
        [D18] => 1
        [E18] => $185
        [F18] => $185
        [A19] => Üniversite Yerleştirme Servisi - Temel
        [D19] => 1
        [E19] => $175
        [F19] => $175
        [A20] => Seyahat ve Sağlık Sigortası
        [D20] => 22 Hafta
        [E20] => $45
        [F20] => $990
        [A21] => Birebir Ders
        [D21] => 10
        [E21] => $75
        [F21] => $750
    )
```

Comment: Plain old `array_merge` will work.

Comment: because I want to assign a new key, it needs to be combined into an array. In this way, I have not reached the first level

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem this way:

```
$keys = array();
$values = array();

foreach ($services_array as $service)
{
    foreach ($service as $key => $value)
    {
        array_push($keys, $key);
        array_push($values, $value);
    }
}
$combine = array_combine($keys, $values);
$merged = array_merge($excel, $combine);
```

Answer (score 0):

A little tricky but:

```
print_r(array_merge($a, array_merge(...$b)));
// `array_merge(...$b)` is done to flatten your second array
```

If you use php5.5 and older:

```
print_r(array_merge($a, call_user_func_array('array_merge', $b)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to achieve this by `array_map()`

```
<?php
   array_map(function($arr) use(&$arr1){
       $arr1 = array_merge($arr1, $arr);
   }, $arr2);
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($arr1);
```

Check here the working one https://paiza.io/projects/LTRGBa6QeMdQOsh2emfMsA?language=php

Answer (score 0):

Spread and flatten the second array, then unionize the newly formed associative array with the first associative array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KtW05))

```
var_export($array1 + array_merge(...$array2));
```

Or feed `array_replace()` with the first array, then the spread second array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gLqT4))

```
var_export(array_replace($array1, ...$array2));
```

Or same technique with `array_merge()`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8VKUT))

```
var_export(array_merge($array1, ...$array2));
```